# AJAX & PHP response gives "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am using AJAX to make a call to a validation script. On return of `$response` I keep getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. I wouldn't be surprised if I am not returning my data properly formatted as JSON, but now I've run the response `{ "loggedIn": false }` in a JSON parser and it seems valid. What am I doing wrong?

`ajaxexample.php`

```
<form method="post" name="login">
    <input type="text" name="username" > Email/Username: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" > Password: <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).on( 'submit', $("#login"), function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = '{"login":[ {'+
                        '"username":"'+$('input[name="username"]').val()+'",'+
                        '"password":"'+$('input[name="password"]').val()+'"'+
                   '}]}';
   var formData = JSON.parse(formData);

    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "users/validate.php",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: formData,

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "POST",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
    })
      // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
      // The response is passed to the function
      .done(function( data ) {

         $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( JSON.stringify(data) ).appendTo( "body" );
      })
      // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
      // status codes are passed to the function
      .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr.responseText );
      })
      // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
      .always(function( xhr, status ) {

      });
});
</script>
```

`validate.php`

```
<?php require_once '../users/init.php';?>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST))
    {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
          'username' => array('display' => 'Username','required' => true),
          'password' => array('display' => 'Password', 'required' => true)));

        if ($validation->passed()) 
        {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->loginEmail($username, $password, $remember);
            $response = array('loggedIn'=>$login);
            echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode("No data.");
    }
?>
```

Comment: might not be exactly the problem, but you should get rid of the extra linefeed at the top -> remove `?>` til `<?php`. and the trailing `?>`

Comment: `echo json_encode("No data.");` will not be valid json, but only a string

Comment: `json_encode("No data.");` will give you `"No data."`, which `JSON.parse` will accept with no problem and give you `No data.` back.

Comment: `$(document).on( 'submit', $("#login")` should be `$(document).on( 'submit', "#login"`

Comment: `validate.php` was expecting normal form data, not a JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues I see there

Firstly the data you're sending is in the wrong format and also creating a json string then parsing it to an object is unnecessary when you can just create the object in the first place.

```
var formData = {
                 "username": $('input[name="username"]').val(), 
                 "password": $('input[name="password"]').val()
               };
```

And secondly, since your data is in the wrong format `$validation->passed()` is going to be false and you will return no data in the request, which expects json and will give the error you see when it doesn't get any.

```
    if ($validation->passed()) 
    {
        $user = new User();
        $login = $user->loginEmail($username, $password, $remember);
        $response = array('loggedIn'=>$login);
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
    }
    else{
      echo json_encode(array('loggedIn'=>false), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
    }
```

Also, the selector for you form submit handler is wrong, it should be something like

```
$(document).on( 'submit', "[name=login]", function(event){
```

Comment: "creating a json string then parsing it to an object is unnecessary"... I'd go further and say it was just bonkers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to send a content-type header at the top of your script inside the php tags

```
header('content-type: application/json');
```

you maybe outputting extra characters you can try to output buffer like this:

```
<?php

ob_start();
if(isset($_POST))
{

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $validate = new Validate();
    $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
      'username' => array('display' => 'Username','required' => true),
      'password' => array('display' => 'Password', 'required' => true)));

    if ($validation->passed()) 
    {
        $user = new User();
        $login = $user->loginEmail($username, $password, $remember);
        $response = array('loggedIn'=>$login);
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT );
        ob_flush();
    }
}
else
{
    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode("No data.");
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: If there were extra characters in the output you would get a different error like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . in JSON at position 10`

Answer (score -1):

`validate.php` was not expecting a JSON object, but rather just form data in a POST.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" name="login">
    <input type="text" name="username" > Email/Username: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" > Password: <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).on( 'submit', $("#login"), function(event){

    event.preventDefault();


    // Using the core $.ajax() method
    $.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "users/validate.php",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {"username":$('input[name="username"]').val(),
            "password":$('input[name="password"]').val()
    },

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "POST",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
    })
      // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
      // The response is passed to the function
      .done(function( data ) {

         $( "<div class=\"content\">").html( JSON.stringify(data) ).appendTo( "body" );
      })
      // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
      // status codes are passed to the function
      .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
        console.log( "Status: " + status );
        console.dir( xhr.responseText );
      })
      // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
      .always(function( xhr, status ) {

      });
});
</script>
```